# El Fragment de Home se super pone en el DrawerLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-drawerlayout

Estoy desarrollando una app en android y he creado un Drawer, el problema es que tuve que poner un if para que desde el menu se pueda dar logout y cuando hice eso el resto del menu dejo de funcionar, asi que agregue el resto de if pero si e doy a otra opcion del menu aparece pero se superpone home y me aparece como seleccionado el de home, no se a que se deba esto si debo de borrar algo o que. Estoy usando androidx por si es de ayuda y en cada fragment hay ahorita solo un texto, este se superpone con el de home pero si selecciono contact y despues profile, contact si se esconde pero home siempre se superpone, ayuda por favor.

Aqui dejo el codigo para que vean mas o menos:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final long DURATION_TRANSITION = 1000;
private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
private Transition transition;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;

static MainActivity mainActivity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainActivity = this;

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_profile, R.id.nav_history,
            R.id.nav_contact, R.id.nav_logout)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

    navigationView.bringToFront();

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

            int id = menuItem.getItemId();
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            NavigationView nav = findViewById(R.id.nav_profile);

            if (id == R.id.nav_home)
            {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, HomeFragment.newInstance())
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
            else if   (id == R.id.nav_profile)
            {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, ProfileFragment.newInstance())
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
            else if   (id == R.id.nav_history)
            {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, HistoryFragment.newInstance())
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
            else if   (id == R.id.nav_contact)
            {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, ContactFragment.newInstance())
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
            else if (id == R.id.nav_logout)
            {
                transition = new Explode();
                startLoginActivity();
            }

            drawer.closeDrawers();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No podes usar `NavController` y `onNavigationItemSelected` al mismo tiempo, si necesitas usar el `onNavigationItemSelected` deberias quitar esta linea:

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController); //Borrame
```

El `NavController` existe para que controle la navegacion, si piensas manejar la navegacion desde el `onNavigationItemSelected` no deberia hacerte falta el uso de un `NavController`

Comment: Ya no me muestra home como seleccionado, de hecho ya no me muestra ninguno, pero sigue superponiéndose home a los demas fragments e incluso si le doy al propio home las letras se oscurecen mas, es como si existiera un home debajo que nunca desaparece

Comment: Acabo de notar que mientras mas veces le doy a un item del menu mas veces se coloca ese fragment, por ejemplo si le doy 5 veces a profile me tira 5 veces ese fragment

Comment: Quita el .addToBackStack(null) esto hace que cada fragment que agregues se apile al que estaba detras en lugar de remplazarse. Por eso debe ser que cuando tocas 5 veces en un mismo boton se te apilan 5 fragments iguales. Eso sirve para que con el boton de back vuelvas al fragment anterior, pero no creo que te sirva en este caso

Comment: Lo quite pero se siguen apilando :/